# Postman/Pre-request Script get scv file data and save as environment variable

Tags: javascript, json, csv, postman, postman-pre-request-script

When I do postmande run collection, I add the csv file, but I couldn't manage to pull this data and save it to environment variables at the pre-request script stage.after that ı will use this variable from environment in my body section code to update data on the server.

```
console.log(price);

pm.environment.set("istenenDeger", price);

let lojistikmaliyeti = Number(price);

console.log(lojistikmaliyeti);

pm.environment.set("Lojistik Maliyeti", lojistikmaliyeti);
```

The code is as above. My first line is the part where I need to define the data I took from the csv file into the "price" object. I left the part where it pulls data from csv blank.

I tried pm.collectionvariables.get combination or fs library and split but I didn't get the right conclusion

Answer (score 0):

I answered this on the Postman forums, so I'll just repeat that answer here.

https://blog.postman.com/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/

The runner uses a special data dictionary based on the CSV headers, so to reference the values in the CSV file, it should just be data.headername.

For example…

```
console.log(data.price);
```

If you just console log the data object, it will show you all of your test data for that iteration as an object.

```
console.log(data);
```

This also looks like it could be a one liner.

```
pm.environment.set(“Lojistik Maliyeti”, Number(data.price));
```